# Change the keyboard language in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, keyboard, uikit

How can i change the keyboard language in the swiftUI. The uikit property is also ok.
I have tried this:

```
public extension UITextField 
{ 
    // ⚠️ Prefer english keyboards
    //
    override var textInputMode: UITextInputMode?
    {
        let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US") // your preferred locale

        return
            UITextInputMode.activeInputModes.first(where: { $0.primaryLanguage == locale.languageCode })
            ??
            super.textInputMode
    }
}
```

But it not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have observed that `UITextInputMode.primaryLanguage` uses `-` instead of `_` in locale string. So if you create locales as `Locale(identifier: "en-US")` instead of `Locale(identifier: "en_US")`, then `UITextInputMode.primaryLanguage` and `locale.identifier` has the same format `en-US`.

```
public extension UITextField
{
    override var textInputMode: UITextInputMode?
    {
        let locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
        
        return
            UITextInputMode.activeInputModes.first(where: { $0.primaryLanguage == locale.identifier })
            ??
            super.textInputMode
    }
}
```